# Disable upload after downloading with DownloadManager

Tags: android, upload, google-plus, battery, download-manager

I am using the `DownloadManager` to download my App-Data. After the downloading is finished I see in the Log following:

```
I/iu.UploadsManager﹕ End new media; added: 0, uploading: 0, time: 151 ms
```

many many times. It seems, that it tries to upload my downloaded files somewhere. I figured out, this Log is caused by Google+. If I stop Google+, the Log stops printing this lines. Yesterday it killed my Battery in 3 hours I guess.

Does anyone had the same problem after using the `DownloadManager`?

- Google+ auto synchronisation is turned off

Comment: Are you sure it's your app that's causing it? It seems to be a problem with the Google+ app in general. Here's just one recent posting I found on [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/-t2698406/page4). I found many others similar.

Comment: Yes it also shows the path to the files the `DownloadManager` downloaded before and they are my files. It always start logging this after/while downloading my files. Even if the downloading is done, it still keeps logging this.